# How to clone Style element with its cssRules?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a style tag with css properties added with [insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) function.

I tried `Element.cloneNode(tree)`, but it does not contain the cssRules

```js
// Add a style tag to head
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.id = "style",
style.type = "text/css",
document.head.appendChild(style);

// Insert some stylesheet rules
var sheet = style.sheet;
sheet.insertRule("p {background-color: red}", sheet.cssRules.length);
sheet.insertRule("p {color: white}", sheet.cssRules.length);
console.log(style.sheet); //Display an object with Css rules

// Try to clone
var styleClone = style.cloneNode(true);
console.log(styleClone.sheet); //Display null !
```

I expect `styleClone.sheet` to be equal to `style.sheet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloned node doesn't get its own `sheet` property (or `CSSStyleSheet` object) until it is added to be part of the document `<head>` or `<body>`

We can give `styleClone` variable it's own `sheet` by inserting it to the head like the code is doing for `style` variable!

Here's what I got

```js
// Add style a tag to head
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.id = "style",
style.type = "text/css",
document.head.appendChild(style);

// Insert some stylesheet rules
var sheet = style.sheet;
sheet.insertRule("p {background-color: red}", sheet.cssRules.length);
sheet.insertRule("p {color: white}", sheet.cssRules.length);
console.log(style.sheet); //Display an object with Css rules

// Try to clone
var styleClone = style.cloneNode(true);
console.log(styleClone.sheet); //Display null !

// Added
document.head.appendChild(styleClone);
// Copy all rules from style variable
for (var i = 0; i < style.sheet.rules.length; i++) {
  styleClone.sheet.insertRule(style.sheet.rules[i].cssText)
}
```

Comment: A deep clone should have the same properties as the original. I do not understand why it does not contain the **sheet** object!
For now I'm doing as you proposed with a loop on the original
Thank you !

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why you're trying to do it that way. My example is way more easier and banal but it does what you're asking for (if I got it right).

```js
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    style.id = "style",
    style.type = "text/css",
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    // create the clone element
    var clone = document.createElement("style");
    clone.id = "clone",
    clone.type = "text/css",
    document.head.appendChild(clone);
    // set the original style as you want
    style.innerHTML = "p {color:red}";
    // copy the same content of style into clone
    clone.innerHTML = style.innerHTML;
```

Insert this code into a script and load it via [onload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) or whatever you want.

Comment: This will not work, I need a clone with the **sheet.cssRules** of the **original** element (style)