# CSSStyleSheet object can't be cloned

Tags: javascript

I would like to use a `CSSStyleSheet` object in a redux store. However when I try to clone this kind of object I get an empty object.

```js
const styleContainer = document.createElement('style')
styleContainer.innerHTML = 'p{color:green}';
document.head.appendChild(styleContainer);

const sheet = styleContainer.sheet
console.log(sheet); // [Object]
console.log({ ...sheet }); // {}
console.log(Object.assign({}, sheet)); // {}
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sheet))); // {}
```

Comment: `CSSStyleSheet` is not a primitive type, so you have to serialise and deserialise it manually. Then re-create it when you need it.

Comment: This questions seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156252/how-to-clone-style-element-with-its-cssrules

Comment: @AasthaBist I have already seen this question ...

Comment: @RobZombie I don't understand why I can't clone it  using spread operator sorry. Even if it is not a primitive type it usually works.

Comment: @arnaudpf I left a reply below.

Answer (score 0):

When you type the following statement:

```
{ ...sheet }
```

it's probably translated into:

```
Object.assign({}, sheet);
```

or in essence `Object.assign()` can be rewritten as:

```
var newObject = {};

Object.keys(sheet).forEach((key) => {
  newObject[key] = sheet[key];
});
```

Which copies all enumerable properties to the newly created `Object`. `prototype` will not be copied either so even if the object solely relies on enumerable properties to function, it won't be the same object, neither a copy of it.

Also note that spread is a shallow copy, it's merely copying primitive types and references to objects and you can verify that empirically:

```
var b = { x: true }; 
var a = { b: b };

a.b == b // true
a.b == { x: true } // false
```

Back to `CSSStyleSheet`. All native classes visible in JavaScript are backed by native classes implemented in C/C++. You can confirm that empirically:

```
var s = new CSSStyleSheet()


s.addRule.toString()
// "function addRule() {
//    [native code]
//"

s.prototype
// undefined
```

Note that functions on such objects say `[native code]` and there is no prototype.

When you spread such object, that connection with native class becomes severed and a generic `Object` is produced instead.

I would suggest to serialize the object yourself and then re-create it when you need it.

For example you could serialize CSS rules and store them in Redux:

```
var stylesheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
stylesheet.replaceSync('p { color: green; }');

var payload = "";
var rules = stylesheet.cssRules;
for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
  payload += rules[i].cssText + "\n";
}

reduxStore.dispatch({ type: 'STORE_CSS', payload: payload });
```

Then when you need to manipulate the CSS stylesheet, you could re-create the `CSSStyleSheet` object and feed it with CSS rules:

```
var stylesheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
stylesheet.replaceSync(payloadFromReduxStore);
```

Note that at the time of writing this, Safari does not support the programmatic instantiation of `CSSStyleSheet` objects but Firefox does.

So perhaps going via `style` tag would be necessary to workaround that, i.e in some browsers:

```
vary styleContainer = document.createElement('style');
styleContainer.innerHTML = 'p { color:green }';
document.head.appendChild(styleContainer);

var stylesheet.replaceSync = styleContainer.sheet
```